# How to solve non-linear constrained optimization in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, optimization

I have to solve a nonlinear constrained function in matlab. and I am not familiar to it's command.
the problem is:

```
minimize E(b,c)   

constrains k1< c.b^0.5< k2 and c/6>k3
```

*note*: `E(b,c)` is a nonlinear function; also how can I solve this easier one

```
minimize E(b,c)  
constrains c.b^0.5=k2 and c/6>k3
```

I must use matlab mfile. please suggest me what should I do!
for simplicity imagine: i.e. `E(b,c)=b^2+√c+c` and `k1=8,k2=12,k3=5`
I must use Matlab mfile. Please suggest me what should I do!
I would like to plot the `E(b,c)` based on given constraints and find the `b,c` pairs, if that is possible.
I am not sure if I really need optimization toolbox or not.
Please give me a short Matlab script if it's ok.
thanks in advance

Comment: Use `fmincon`: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html. You need the optimization toolbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be non-linear constrained optimization. Check, if your objective function is convex or not. Save you objective function and constraints in an m.file. Use optimization toolbox, select a solver that best suits your problem [Please refer http://in.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/choosing-a-solver.html?refresh=true for choosing the right solver and right algorithm.]